# Как одной ячейке присвоить несколько связей?

Tags: php, laravel

Пример: Есть две таблицы: категории и товары.
Категории: id, name.
Товары: id, category_id, title, desc, price.
Как одному товару добавить несколько категорий(связей): например category_id: 1, 3, 5

Comment: laravel тут при чем?

Answer (score 1):

Переделать структуру под 3 таблицы: `categories`, `items`, `category_item`.
В категориях оставить id, name. В товарах id, title, desc, price. В третьей таблице `category_id`, `item_id`. Если вы используете laravel, как указано в тегах, можно воспользоваться такими миграциями:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
});
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('desc');
    $table->string('price');
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('category_item', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('item_id')->constrained();
});
```

И в моделях указать связи:

```
// Models\Category
public function items(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
}

// Models\Item
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

После этого сможете в третьей таблице указывать Id товара и id нужной категории в отдельных записях и получать все категории, принадлежащие товару, а также все товары, принадлежащие категории.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можно как то сделать без создания 3 таблицы?

Comment: @needko связи многие-ко-многим реализуются через третью таблицу